# Extra characters and order changes in terminal output? Is this a terminal problem (CoCalc)?

Tags: python, list, terminal

Why am I seeing extra ] characters in output of a list construction that should have just a list of lists? Is this a terminal problem (using CoCalc's terminal)?

Particularly, the output should have just two levels of lists, the global list and each of the sublists inside it.

But when I read through the output of data in a Python interpreter in [**CoCalc's terminal**](https://www.cocalc.com/). Then I see this kind of thing:

[image]

**Notice the extra ] as if there was inner lists that should not exist. Also notice the numbering which seems to not be in order, even though in the data it is ordered.**

What's happening here?

---

**To reconstruct the problem**:

Download the dorothea_valid.data file from here:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/dorothea/DOROTHEA/

Then create a project in CoCalc (https://cocalc.com/). Upload dorothea_valid.data to that project.

Start a Linux terminal in CoCalc, and make sure you know the path/working directory so that you can find dorothea_valid.data from Python. In the Linux terminal start the Python interpreter by writing `python`.

Paste the following function meant for reading a file with sequences of integer values separated by "\n" to the interpreter:

```
def read_datafile(fname):
    data = list()
    with open(fname, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            data.append([int(i) for i in line.split()])
    return data

# and then call print(read_datafile(fname)) to get the output.
```

Then call read_datafile() on dorothea_valid.data, and then print the resulting object as suggested in the above comment. The screen captured lines are seen when scrolling right to the bottom, however problems may be seen from other parts of the output as well.

**EDIT:
It's now 10/08/2022 and I'm unable to see the problem. Maybe it has been fixed in CoCalc.**

Comment: Please post the output as text, not an image. Also, you should create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You have no `print` statements, so I'm not sure how you are getting any output for us to look at.

Comment: Perhaps you want `data.extend([int(i) for i in line.split()])`. With `append` each line is its own list in the list called `data`.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating inner lists. You're using one list comprehension per line of the file so it's making one list of integers per line. If you want it all as one list, use `extend` rather than `append`:

```
for line in file:
    data.extend(int(i) for i in line.split())
```

Notice I'm using a generator expression here rather than a list comprehension. Using a list comprehension is a waste becaues it creates the whole list in memory only to be read through once and then discarded.

Comment: Thanks. What about the problem of seeing the order of integers mixed?

Comment: Also when replacing append with extend I see: https://i.imgur.com/bxmMnUp.jpg. So is there still some problem? Or is this something odd in the output of CoCalc terminal perhaps?

Comment: It does look like a terminal problem. It should be printing the prompt (>>>)  in the middle of the output either. Not at all surprised if some web based IDE is broken. Try using python or ipython locally.

Comment: BTW, this answer does not answer the question. Because the intention was to read the data as [[],[],...,[]]. The code is right, the terminal wasn't.